# Is there a way to speed up file uploads?

Tags: asp.net, file, file-upload

I understand that file upload speeds are limited by the upload speed of the internet connection among other things.  Is it possible to use jquery or some other method to compress the file locally before upload and then upload a file to the server? Any other solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While others have already provided answers, one thing you *might* be able to do (depending on how your website is setup) is, once the user has chosen the file, begin the upload process immediately.  That way, if the user has to fill in additional information about the file (maybe a description of the file, a different name for the server, keywords, etc), their file is uploading in the meantime, and the information can be provided later.

Other than that, you're SOL.

Comment: This appears to be the technique Gmail uses when uploading attachments.

Answer (score 2):

If upload speed is a concern, perhaps consider a client side application the user has to download.

Or a flash based uploader. Using flash you'd get more control over the upload and it is consistent across browsers. This is what YouTube does to allow 2GB video uploads with minimal stress on the user's part. It doesn't make it faster if the client's connection is poor, but it helps with the reliability of the upload.

Answer (score 0):

The browser already takes care of all the little optimizations that would make it faster on the client side, so no, you can't really use JavaScript to speed up a file upload. There isn't much you can do if the clients connection is the bottle neck.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't read the local filesystem in JavaScript.  You can't do it with Flash or Java under the default config, either (with the partial exception of Flash 10).  Further, there is no standard way to send compressed requests (the way there is for responses).

Answer (score 0):

The upload time will be determined by a variety of factors. So, for example, network speed, web server response time, upload file size, and so on. Check with your IT department and go over those points. If the issue is one of file size, there are ways to compress and reduce file size in Android. Refer to this sample code for Android compression and document capture.

https://github.com/ExtrieveTechnologies/QuickCapture